# How does one call a function in a Python program from command line

Tags: python, windows, cmd

For example let's say I have a file called myscript.py

This file contains the following code.

```
foo(var):
   return var
```

How would I call the function foo with argument var on command line.

I know that I can go to the directory myscript.py is placed in and type.

```
>>> python myscript.py
```

Which will run myscript.py. The only problem is myscript.py doesn't automatically call foo when it is run.

I have tried using

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo( )
```

Which does not work for me. For some reason when I do that nothing happens. I get no error message and nothing is called.

Comment: Return returns it to the caller. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: `foo` is being called. You're just a) not passing anything to it, and b) It doesn't do anything. You'll want to use argparse or `sys` to handle input from the cli

Comment: how do you know that "nothing is called". In your example you just discard whatever your function returns.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get any output because you don't generate any. Try calling [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
def foo(var):
    print(var)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo('Hello, world')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `sys` module to pass arguments from the command line.
You can do this:

```
import sys

def foo(var):
  return var

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # arguments check
  if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "USAGE: %s <value>" % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(1)

  # get the agument so as to use it to the function call
  arg = sys.argv[1]

  # call the function using this argument
  val = foo(arg)

  # print the returned value
  print val
```

Then you can run your python script by this command:
`python myscript.py 3`
giving as argument e.g. the number 3